# File extension detection mechanism

Tags: file, extension-methods

How Application will detect file extension?

I knew that every file has header that contains all the information related to that file.
My question is how application will use that header to detect that file?

Every file in file system associated some metadata with it for example, if i changed audio file's extension from .mp3 to .txt and then I opened that file with VLC but still VLC is able to play that file.
I found out that every file has header section which contains all the information related to that file.
I want to know how can I access that header?

Comment: Please refer updated question.

Comment: Can u provide what technologies/languages are You using while working with that files?

Comment: In what way do you want to access the header data? Do you want to read it in hexadecimal, or words?

Comment: In what way I can extract the information from the file header,could you be more specific about how to extract the  information from file header?

Comment: @Jan Walczak It's not  specific to app/ technologies .

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some more details:

A file extension is basically a way to indicate the format of the data (for example, TIFF image files have a [format specification](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)).

This way an application can check if the file it handles is of the right format.

Some applications don't check (or accept wrong) file formats and just tries to use them as the format it needs. So for your `.mp3` file, the data in this file is **not** changed when you simply change the extension to `.txt`.

When VLC reads the `.txt` byte by byte and interprets it as a `.mp3` it can just extract the correct music data from that file.

Now some files include a header for extra validation of what kind of format the data inside the file is. For example a unicode text file (should) include a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to indicate how the data in the file needs to be handled. This way an application can check whether the header tag matches the expected header and so it knows for sure that your '.txt` file actually contains data in the 'mp3' format.

Now there are quite some applications to read those header tags, but they are often specific for each format. This [TIFF Tag Viewer](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html) for example (I used it in the past to check the header tags from my TIFF files).

So or you could just open your file with some kind of [hex viewer](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) and then look at the format specifications what every bytes means, or you search Google for a header viewer for the format you want to see them.

Comment: Thanks ..
seems like the hex viewer i can use for mostly all type of file.

Comment: Of course you can: every file is made out of bits, and so out of bytes, and bytes can be represented with hexadecimal values. The only thing is that you then have to figure out what every piece of data means (with a format specifier)